# Creating line chart out of timeseries dataframe gives ValueError in plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, plotly

I have a time series dataframe (dummy) as below, for which I am trying to create a line chart using plotly to plot the values of all the columns on y axis while index is the x axis. All the columns of the dataframe have the same number of rows and upon checking the type of the index, it is 'dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]'

However, while creating the line chart as per code below, I get the following error: "ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument y is 5, whereas the length of previously-processed arguments ['time_before_fulfilment'] is 109". I went through other stack overflow answers and tried a couple of things but couldn't solve it.

Could someone kindly help?

```
# Code to create dummy dataframe
data = {
    '2001-07-21 10:00:00+05:00': [45, 51, 31, 3],
    '2001-07-21 10:15:00+05:00': [46, 50, 32, 3],
    '2001-07-21 10:30:00+05:00': [47, 51, 34, 7],
    '2001-07-21 10:45:00+05:00': [50, 50, 33, 9]
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['2001-07-21 10:45:00+05:00', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
df.index.name = 'date'
df = df.rename_axis(index=None, columns='date').T
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True)
df.index = df.index.tz_convert(pytz.FixedOffset(60))

# Show the DataFrame
df
```

```
Dataframe

                            2001-07-21 10:45:00+05:00     Col 2     Col 3      Col 4
date
2001-07-21 10:00:00+05:00      45                           51       31         3  
2001-07-21 10:15:00+05:00      46                           50       32         3
2001-07-21 10:30:00+05:00      47                           51       34         7
2001-07-21 10:45:00+05:00      50                           50       33         9
```

Code

```
def plot_graph():

    fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = [df.columns[0],'Col2','Col3','Col4'] , markers='.')
    
    fig.update_xaxes(
        rangeslider_visible=True,
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count = 1, label = "1H", step = "hour", stepmode ="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        )
    )
    fig.show()

plot_graph()
```

Comment: You need to remove ```df.columns[0]``` from the list passed to ```y```

Comment: My apologies, the question has slightly wrong information. I've corrected it now. Could you take a look again?

Comment: Can you provide the dateframe as code example to make it easier to help

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code for the dataframe. But it is a dummy dataframe.

Comment: Why is one of the column name a datetime field ?

Comment: It is stocks data, the demand of the data needs the column name to be that way.

Comment: I don't actually get it by your problem here is basically you are passing a dataframe with 4 columns only and giving the y variable 5 column names, you need to make it 4 also.

Comment: I found the issue, the problem is that the column name '2001-07-21 10:45:00+05:00' is a timestamp. Need to convert the name of the column to be of type str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this question, so that someone with a similar issue can get some insight. The problem was that the column name '2001-07-21 10:45:00+05:00' is a timestamp which needed to be converted to type str. Doing that fixed the issue and the plotly code generated the desired line graph

Code:

```
##Converting the column name from type timestamp to str
timestamp = pd.Timestamp(df_main.columns[0])
date_string = timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
df= df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: date_string})
df
```